# Update svn client (via tortoisesvn or command line)

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-client

When in Windows command line I input this:

```
svn merge -rHEAD:149258 MySVNPath MyLocalPath
```

I get error:

```
svn: E155021: This client is too old to work with the workign copy at 'MyLocalPath' (format 31). You need to get a newer Subversion client.
```

Stupid question, how do I do that, how to update client?
Is there a simple way just to update the svn client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download built binaries of subversion, for example from here: http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion
Install it. Make sure that only latest client's folder (newly installed) is available in PATH Windows environment variable.

Comment: Is there really no "simple" way, like command "svn client update" or something.
May be since I have TortoiseSVN it's better to download and install new tortoiseSVN?

Comment: Yes, you can install TortoiseSVN, its latest installations contain command line svn client as well.